# Difference between <> and NOT operator in Microsoft Access?

Tags: microsoft-access

What might the difference between "<>" and "NOT" operator be when used in Microsoft Access?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NOT` is a unary operator which complements its argument, eg

- `NOT(TRUE)` is equivalent to `FALSE`

In contrast `<>` is a binary operator which compares two values, eg

- `1<>0` is equivalent to `TRUE`, or to `NOT(1=0)`

This latter equivalence is the only sense in which the two are connected.

Answer (score 0):

`NOT Operator` Operation involving NOT  operator is known as ‘Logical Negation’. This operation is performed on only one input or operand. It returns the value of TRUE if the input is FALSE and vice-versa.
[Not Operator](http://www.blueclaw-db.com/accessquerysql/not.htm) is the not true of your operation like

Not Null (is not null)
Not = (not equal)
Not In (Not Exist)
but <> is just different from any value or not = to the value

Comment: "but <> is just different from" - different from what? How is it different? You seen to have written half an answer.